# What is the "Manage API Keys" link to the right of the StackApps.com frontpage?

Tags: support, stackapps

When I click on it, I get a page that goes "Your Applications", then "No applications registered". Needless to say, this is different from "**Manage your applications**" link on the frontpage because I do have an application registered and it's shown there.

It appears that "**Manage API Keys**" has nothing to do with my OAuth2 access tokens either because I do have an access token for my own app and I don't see the token there.

So what is it, exactly? Under what circumstances would I see something there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Manage API Keys" link takes you to your list of registered API 1.x applications. Since the 1.x versions of the API are now deprecated, you won't be seeing anything new show up there.

All new applications that you register for API 2.x will instead show on the "Manage your applications" page.